# How to get a .bin file from a BIOS .exe file to re-program the BIOS chip of an Acer Aspire XC-603, using a CH341 programmer?

Tags: bios, acer-aspire

I have a difficult question but quite simple to express......from Acer's download driver page I have a BIOS file. Unzipped it has an .exe file and a Flash.bat file etc.

I gather to program a bios chip I will need a .bin file extracted from this collection...Am I dreaming to think this is possible?

My PC is totally bricked, beeps and all. No DOS no screen, just the distant sound of other life. So I can't just run the .exe and look in the App/data/Temp file...I tried that on another PC and it tells me the PC will not support the .exe. Anyway, if you can suggest something I would be very thankful.

Comment: "*I gather ...*" -- That sounds like you're guessing and don't have a specific set of instructions. Until you actually have a procedure specific for your programmer and chip, you don't know what else you may need. Maybe the programmer needs a HEX file? "*My PC is totally bricked ...*" -- Then you have more problems than just obtaining a suitable file. A reprogrammed BIOS may not even solve a dead PC. A "bad" BIOS is rarely the cause of a  dead mobo.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The problem did occur because of a failed BIOS update. So I can only assume the BIOS chip is scrambled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue due to corrupted BIOS and I fixed it at home.  Run the `.exe` file on another PC and don't close the window. Go to `C:\Users\[current user]\AppData\Temp` and find the folder which vanishes once you close the dialogue box from the `.exe` file.

Open that folder and there will be an `inflash.bin` file. Copy it to the desktop and open it using a hex editor. Search for `.fd` in the code using find option and copy the file name that comes in front of it in the code. Rename the `.bin` file to this name along with the `.fd` extension. You will now have your BIOS file.

I booted my PC with a copy of it on an inserted flash drive, and pressed the keys <kbd>Func</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> keys as it started. It worked.

Comment: Hi. Thank you! You are the only person to try and explain this to me. When I run the BIOS.exe  the dialogue box appears and without closing it I look in the Appdata/Temp and there is nothing new there

Comment: This is the Acer downloads page link for my PC....https://www.acer.com/au-en/support?search=Aspire%20XC-603&filter=global_download&suggest=XC-603;2........the BIOS I am after is P11-BO. If you like, see if the same happens when you try. I'm not sure if it's some setting in my windows that is stopping the BIOS files from going to the Appdata/Temp files. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also try unpacking the exe using 7zip or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help. I just solved my problem via another forum. Somebody there was kind enough to post an Aspire AXC-603G BIOS dump file that I used with the CH341A programmer and a SOP connector to the chip itself. I programmed it with AS Programmer and bingo the machine works again! I had learnt that programming the BIOS chip with Acer's update files would not work as they are not the complete BIOS image. Give me a shout if anyone needs help with a similar problem...or if you need the BIOS dump file itself.